# How to create a simple form to redirect the user to entered URL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to create a simple form to redirect the visitors to a relative path they enter.

I want to show only a simple search form and if the user enter a word then submit search button, it should redirect the user to `example.com/advanced-search?full_text=word`.

**How can I do this with only PHP or with JS?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set form and input field with name of full_text like this:

```
<form action="advanced-search" method="GET">
   <input type="search" name="full_text">
   <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```